# SQL check constraint multiple conditions

Tags: sql

The team has decided that, except for the gm and catchers, a player
     name should not exceed 10 letters.  Implement this as a check constraint.

Table: (table name: empbbb02)
EMPNO ENAME

```
EMPNO ENAME      POS          BOSS HIREDATE         SAL     DEPTNO INCENTIVES
----- ---------- ------------ ---- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
712   rickey     gm                01-JAN-98      10000         40
735   lasorda    coach        712  10-JAN-98       2000         40
707   bochy      coach        712  11-JAN-98       2000         40
798   berra      coach        712  12-JAN-98       2000         40
782   musial     right field  707  01-FEB-98      42000         20
763   gehrig     first base   735  11-MAR-98      85000         10
777   minoso     shortstop    735  05-MAY-98      85000         10       6000
721   sandberg   second base  735  28-FEB-98      25000         10
788   cey        third base   735  10-JAN-99      15000         10       8000
720   williams   left field   707  05-JAN-99      15000         20
755   johnson    pitcher      798  08-NOV-98      50000         30
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific RDBMS you're using. Like it recommended in that big box when you chose the `sql` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a check constraint to your table:

```
alter table empbbb02 add check (char_length(ename) <= 10 or pos in ('gm','catcher'))
```

Comment: Yeah, maybe. But if the OP is using, say, Oracle or SQL Server then this is completely wrong.

Comment: No Oracle tag there, no dbms specified, so ANSI SQL is assumed. Why downvote for a perfect answer?

Comment: If you can't possibly know whether the code is correct you can't claim that it's a "perfect" answer. As most RDBMS don't perfectly implement ANSI SQL, you also can't assume that this is what's required (and in general assuming things isn't the best). We have a specific tag for ANSI SQL ([tag:ansi-sql]), if this is what's required.

Comment: "Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ANSI SQL as much as possible."

Comment: Yes, and _"Questions should include code examples and table structure, and include a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server) being used."_ It's all meaningless though, do you want me to remove that line you've just quoted :-)?  It makes sense for answers to be a portable as possible, and this just isn't - as already stated it won't work in Oracle or SQL Server, it'll also fail in SQLite and fail silently in MySQL.

Comment: No dbms is specified, no one else has answered, and I wrote an ANSI SQL answer (not knowing about Oracle's and SQL Server's missing support). I can't really see why I get downvoted and told it's completely wrong if Oracle or SQL Server... A constructive comment would be fine.

Comment: I really don't have the time to engage in a massively extended conversation. I've removed the downvote, but _please_ do not answer a question unless you know you're right. No matter how many times you use the phrase "ANSI SQL" you will **not** be correct in a minority of cases and you're suggesting something that will not work in the majority (Given MySQL's, Oracle's and SQL Servers' market share). It's worth ensuring that the answer you're providing will actually work before providing it.

Comment: `char_length()` doesn't exist in SQL Server, Oracle or SQLite @a_horse and not including the `constraint` keyword is (surprisingly) okay according to SQL-92. This'll work in PostgreSQL for instance.